# mysql select with IF or CASE and subquery

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables: `pf_rows`

```
|  g1  |  g2  |  g3  |  g4  |
+------+------+------+------+
| foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo4 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

and `pf_seq`

```
| lite | qty |
+------+-----+
|  1   |  12 |
+------+-----+
|  2   |  12 |
+------+-----+
```

I need a query which returns values from `pf_rows` based value what resides in `pf_seq`.
Like: when `pf_seq.lite=1` then result be `foo1` and when `pf_seq.lite=2` then result be `foo2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the two tables are not related, you will have to use a `cross join`

```
select  t2.lite,
        case
            when t2.lite = 1 then t1.g1
            when t2.lite = 2 then t1.g2
            /* other cases if needed */
            else null
        end as gx
from    pf_rows t1
cross join
        pf_seq t2
```

Note that this kind of query is not performing at all if the tables contain large amounts of rows.